# Urn problem with choice

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I would like to know whether I have solved correctly the following problem, from Henk Tijms's *Understanding Probability*.

> For a final exam, your professor gives you a list of 15 items to
>   study. He indicates that he will choose eight for the actual exam. You
>   will be required to answer five of those. You decide to study 10 of
>   the 15 items. What is the probability that you will pass for the exam?

I think that this problem can be considered as an urn drawing problem, with 10 white balls (the topics that the student knows) and 5 black balls (the topics that are not known).

Out of 8 extractions, the favorable outcomes are those where $5,6,7$ or $8$ white balls are extracted. This leads to the probability:

$$
P = \sum_{k=0}^3 \frac{\binom{10}{5+k}\binom{5}{3-k}}{\binom{15}{8}}=\frac{9}{11}\simeq 0.818.
$$

Comment: Seems good to me.

Comment: @Arthur My understanding is that this falls under the hyper-geometric probability. If that's the case, why do I get different result? if I use the http://bit.ly/2CRvuUr calculator with P=15, p=8, S=10, s=8 I get x>=5 of 0.818.

Comment: I would agree with Arthur and you, except that I find it doubtful that someone who would choose such a strategy would have 100% probability of answering the items they did study correctly.;-)

Comment: @adhg Because I hadn't checked the actual calculations. It's the right expression in the sum, but the result of that sum is $\frac{585}{715}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I like the way you 'paraphrase' the question into something very familiar and similar! When I looked into your answer it made sense but the end result is (a bit) off.

The problem falls under the hyper-geometric probability domain and hence the accumulative result is

$$
=\frac{585}{715}\simeq 0.818.
$$

When I perform the accumulative result manually I always forget something so I always check it with an online calculator. If you check the result [here](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/hypergeometric.aspx), you'll see that for the given parameters:

```
P=15, 
p=8, 
S=10, 
s=5
```

the result is `P(x>=5)=0.818`. Hope this helps and thanks for @Arthur for confirming my analysis.

Comment: Thanks, indeed there was I mistake in the computation, fixed just now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "passing" means answering all 5 questions, the method looks good.